# Nginx + Tomcat working in the same server

Tags: tomcat, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm developing a WebApp using Tomcat. I've set a frontal NGINX server to serve static content and redirect the rest of work to a Tomcat server.

I've set that configuration in NGINX:

```
proxy_cache_path  /var/www/mysite/assets levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:10m inactive=60m;
proxy_cache_key   "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";

server {
        server_name             mysite.com www.mysite.com;
        listen                  443 ssl http2;

        ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/mysite.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/mysite.key;
        ssl_session_cache       shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout     10m;

        root                    /opt/tomcat/latest/webapps/mysite/;
        index                   index.jsp;

        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|xml|gz)$ {
                expires 12h;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8080/mysite/;
                proxy_redirect          off;
                proxy_set_header        Host $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header        X-Server-Proto $server_protocol;

                proxy_cache             my_cache;
                add_header              X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
        }
}
```

As you can see, I set the proxy redirect and the proxy cache. Using the last directive (`add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;`) I could see if a hva e HIT or a MISS loading resources.

The problems I found are:

1. If I use this configuration, I think can't see the HIT/MISS headers,
   so **I don't know if it's working well the proxy cache**.
2. If I comment the entire `location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|xml|gz)$` section, I can see the HIT/MISS headers, so **I think the proxy cache works**, but I don't know if I'm letting Tomcat manage static content, and that is what I wanted to avoid using this section

How could I set the config file to use a proxy cache and let NGINX manage the static content (jpg,css,js,...)? 
Maybe everything is alright and I've got it well...
Which is the best solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having `add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;` in the NGINX config means that NGINX looks at `expires` set on those assets coming from Tomcat and caches them appropriately.

The additional `location` block

```
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|xml|gz)$ {
                expires 12h;
}
```

combined with

```
root                    /opt/tomcat/latest/webapps/mysite/;
```

will server them from disk and not the proxy, eliminating the need for hitting the proxy cache.

Comment: So, I should remove the proxy_cache line and the last one, isn't it? (And the first two lines that set the cache, I guess)

Comment: Depends on where you want to set the `expires` and other details. If you just want to keep it as it is remove the `location ~*` and leave the `proxy_cache` in.

If you want more fine grained control over the cached assets maybe you can do something like in this example here https://belvg.com/blog/static-content-caching-with-nginx.html where you add the `proxy_pass` to the assets as well.